# How to accept string using doubly linked list in C programming?

Tags: c, string

here i have made a structure for DLL :-

```
struct node
{
    char letter;
    struct node* prev;
    struct node* next;
};
```

and this is the function to accept the string :-

```
struct node* accept(struct node* head)
{
    int i=0;
    char dummy, ch;
    struct node* memory, *memory1;
    memory = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    printf("\n Enter the letters ");
    scanf("%c",&dummy);
    ch = getchar();
    if(ch == '\n')
    {
        return head;
    }
    memory->letter = ch;
    memory->prev = NULL;
    memory->next = NULL;
    head = memory;
    while(ch!='\n')
    {
        ch = getchar();
        memory1 = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        memory1->letter = ch;
        memory1->prev = memory;
        memory1->next = NULL;
        memory = memory1;
        i++;
    }
    n = i;
    return head;
}
```

and below is the almost half completed program :-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    char letter;
    struct node* prev;
    struct node* next;
};

int n= 0;

struct node* accept(struct node* head)
{
    int i=0;
    char dummy, ch;
    struct node* memory, *memory1;
    memory = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    printf("\n Enter the letters ");
    scanf("%c",&dummy);
    ch = getchar();
    if(ch == '\n')
    {
        return head;
    }
    memory->letter = ch;
    memory->prev = NULL;
    memory->next = NULL;
    head = memory;
    while(ch!='\n')
    {
        ch = getchar();
        memory1 = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(char));
        memory1->letter = ch;
        memory1->prev = memory;
        memory1->next = NULL;
        memory = memory1;
        i++;
    }
    n = i;
    return head;
}

void display(struct node* head)
{
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n Nothing to display .. ");
        return ;
    }
    struct node* temp;
    temp = head;
    printf("\n");
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%c",temp->letter);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void reverseDisplay(struct node* head)
{
    struct node* temp;
    temp = head;
    while(temp!= NULL)
    {
        reverseDisplay(temp->next);
    }
    printf("%c",temp->letter);
}

struct node* insertChar(struct node* head)
{
    int pos, i;
    char ch;
    struct node* temp, *temp1;
    temp1 = head;
    printf("\n Enter the position where you want to insert a letter : ");
    scanf("%d",&pos);
    if(pos <1 && pos >(n+1))
    {
        printf("\n INVALID POSITION .. ");
    }
    else
    {
        temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(char));
        ch = getchar();
        temp->letter = ch;
        if(ch == '\n')
        {
            return head;
        }
        if(head == NULL)
        {
            temp->next = NULL;
            temp->prev = NULL;
            head = temp;
            return head;
        }
        for(i=1; i<pos-1; i++)
        {
            temp1 = temp1->next;
        }
        temp->next = temp1->next;
        temp1->next = temp;
        temp->prev = temp1;
        temp1->next->prev = temp;
        n++;

    }
    return head;

}

int main()
{
    struct node* head;
    head = NULL;
    int i,ch;
    char c;
    do
    {
    printf("\n Enter your choice :\n");
    printf("\n 1. Accept the string : ");
    printf("\n 2. Display the string : ");
    printf("\n 3. Reverse Display : ");
    printf("\n 4. Insert a character : ");
    printf("\n 5. Delete a character : ");
    printf("\n 6. Modify a character : ");
    printf("\n 7. Revert the string : ");
    printf("\n 8. Exit \n : ");
    scanf("%d",&ch);

    switch(ch)
    {
    case 1: printf("\n Accepting a string ...");
            head = accept(head);
            break;
    case 2:
            printf("\n Displaying the string .. ");
            display(head);
            break;
    case 3:
            printf("\n Reverse Displaying ..");
            if(head == NULL)
            {
                printf("\n There is nothing to be displayed ..");
                break;
            }
            printf("\n");
            reverseDisplay(head);
            break;
    case 4:
            head = insertChar(head);
            break;


    }
    }while(ch!=8);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that when i am choosing to display the text, then this is showing me only the first letter entered into the string. Can't figure it out. Please help me.

few output instances :-

Enter your choice :

1. Accept the string :
2. Display the string :
3. Reverse Display :
4. Insert a character :
5. Delete a character :
6. Modify a character :
7. Revert the string :
8. Exit 
   : 1

   Accepting a string ...
   Enter the letters amit upadhyay

   Enter your choice :
9. Accept the string :
10. Display the string :
11. Reverse Display :
12. Insert a character :
13. Delete a character :
14. Modify a character :
15. Revert the string :
16. Exit 
    : 2

    Displaying the string .. 
    a

    Enter your choice :
17. Accept the string :
18. Display the string :
19. Reverse Display :
20. Insert a character :
21. Delete a character :
22. Modify a character :
23. Revert the string :
24. Exit 
    :

Comment: 1) **Always** check the result of functions which can encounter an error. 2) Do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C! 3) Use a debugger.

Comment: @Olaf user debugger , if you can help me through the idea where i am going wrong and what i should do to improve it. Then please tell me

Comment: hmm, where do you set a ->next to anything but NULL. Looks like you set up the prev links, but not the next links

Comment: Most obvious error: when you `malloc` for a struct, you need to make it the size of the struct: i.e., `memory = malloc(sizeof (struct node));` Since sizeof char is 1 by definition, you're only allocating one byte.

Comment: I think OP is getting away with the malloc() (NO SEGV) because many malloc()s have a minimum size they always give you.

Comment: You should split list-ahndling into seperate functions. This simpifies testing and debugging. In general, use one function for a specific - well - functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing to make a link.

```
while(ch!='\n')
{
   ch = getchar();
   memory1 = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   memory1->letter = ch;
   memory1->prev = memory;
   memory1->next = NULL;

   // The missing link
   memory->next = memory1;

   memory = memory1;
   i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `malloc`s you don't alloc enough space for the two pointer, i.e. use

```
(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

instead of

```
(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(char));
```

You also forgot to initialize the `memory->next` pointer, i.e. add

```
memory->next = memory1;
```

in `struct node* accept(struct node* head)`'s while loop

Comment: still the problem remains the same. While displaying it is only showing the first letter

Comment: well, that was a typing mistake .. even on correcting that the problem remains the same.

Comment: and that should be (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node)), not the one you told. Now reply if you can

Answer (score 1):

You are not asking scanf for string but for char

```
scanf("%c",&dummy);
```

should be:

```
scanf("%s", &dummy);
```

> %c = character 
>   %d = decimal (intiger)
>   %f = flaot
>   %s = string (character array)

scanf() as input reading and printf() as printing output function look for special formatting strings listed above, and then look for input/output values following the string. So when you have `scanf("%d", &value)` scanf will accept all inputs as decimal values, if you do `scanf("%c", &value)` scanf would look for one character and stop after accepting one character, but if you put `scanf("%s", &value)` scanf takes all characters until the break character is entered it is usualy `\n` or `\r` or `\n\r` depending on system

Comment: okay, i did that too, but sir i don't know why we do so. Can you tell me ? why we need to write this statement scanf("%s",&dummy)? please answer

Comment: Edited the question to help you understand.